# Why does Facebook posts scraping become extremely slow or stop after few hundred posts are scraped?

Tags: selenium, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rate-limiting

I was trying to scrape all the community posts from 2016 onwards on a Facebook brand community page like [this](https://www.facebook.com/pg/ATT/community/?ref=page_internal) using `Selenium` and `BeautifulSoup`. I would like to use this data for a research project and I intend on deidentifying the data and deleting any identifiable data subsequently.

After scraping between 300-500 posts, the rest of the posts load extremely slowly or don't even load sometimes. This is probably because of the data rate limits set by Facebook for individual users.

I would like to know how I can overcome this issue. When I reach such a limit, can I wait for `x` minutes before which I can continue again? Is there some parameter I can set to avoid hitting a rate limit? Any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Scraping is not allowed to begin with. (Unless you had Facebook's explicit prior written consent, which I rather doubt here.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I wasn't aware. There seems to be [published research](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/environmental-conservation/article/illegal-wildlife-digital-market-an-analysis-of-chinese-wildlife-marketing-and-sale-on-facebook/D9E1850222C1CD521D309821BE596F74) that has scraped Facebook data though. Is there a procedure to follow to obtain written consent? An email address or application form?

Comment: They provide some data for research purposes under https://research.fb.com/data/, maybe you find how to apply for access to specific data as well there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

i m having the same problem, after doing multiple scrolling the feeds are stopped to be shown and and while verifying network trafic (requests and response ) i find that the error was "rate limit reacheched".
The big problem is that facebook graph api documentation does not show any entry about the limit of request that can be done by the user.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "verifying network trafic (requests and response )"? Please update the answer once you are able to provide some estimates for the rate limits.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is absolutely from your PC/Laptop specifications, I was developing an Instagram bot that scrolls on an famous person's followers to get their usernames to interact later with them, but then I realized that sometimes it is very slow, and sometimes not to get usernames, like most of times it gets 1 username every 3 seconds, but sometimes 5 usernames a second, then I got that if I switch my battery power mode (Battery saver, Better battery, Better performance, Best performance) selenium goes slower and faster, I do not know if there is something similar in MacOS but try it if there is something like that, of course your PC or Laptop would not continue for ever and will start being slow at some place.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried a paid VPN service: NordVPN, which solved the issue. You can choose from multiple VPNs like Express or Nord or whichever you find best fit.

You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77028694/10495410 for detailed process.