# python scrapy is slowing down by the time it is parsing

Tags: python, caching, scrapy, slowdown

I have a scraper bot, which works fine. But as time passes when it is scraping the speed gets down.
I added `concurrent request`, `download_delay:0`,`'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED':False` but result is same. It is starting with a fast pace but gets slower.
I guess it is about caching, but do not know if I have to clean cache, or why it behaves so?
The code is below would like to hear comments;

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd
import scrapy_xlsx

itemList=[]
class plateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapePlate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk']
    FEED_EXPORTERS = {'xlsx': 'scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter'}
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORTERS' :FEED_EXPORTERS,'FEED_FORMAT': 'xlsx','FEED_URI': 'output_r00.xlsx', 'LOG_LEVEL':'INFO','DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0,'CONCURRENT_ITEMS':300,'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS':30,'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED':False}

    def start_requests(self):
        df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        columnA_values=df['PLATE']
        for row in columnA_values:
            global  plate_num_xlsx
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={'plate_num_xlsx': plate_num_xlsx})

    def parse(self, response, plate_num_xlsx=None):
        plate = response.xpath('//div[@class="resultsstrip"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//div[@class="resultsstrip"]/p/text()').extract_first()

        try:
            a = plate.replace(" ", "").strip()
            if plate_num_xlsx == plate.replace(" ", "").strip():
                item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": price.strip()}
                itemList.append(item)
                print(item)
                yield item
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": "-"}
                itemList.append(item)
                print(item)
                yield item
        except:
            item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": "-"}
            itemList.append(item)
            print(item)
            yield item

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(plateScraper)
process.start()

import winsound
winsound.Beep(555,333)
```

EDIT: "log_stats"

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1791806,
 'downloader/request_count': 3459,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3459,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 38304184,
 'downloader/response_count': 3459,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3459,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 6,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3056.810985,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 27, 22, 31, 17, 17188),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 238767410,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 3459,
 'item_scraped_count': 3459,
 'log_count/INFO': 61,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3459,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3459,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3459,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3459,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3459,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 27, 21, 40, 20, 206203)}
2023-01-28 02:31:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: can You please provide the latest log output entries from this code sample? (last log lines after `Dumping Scrapy stats`)

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest reasons of going slow down scraping data is to set high volumes of the `CONCURRENT_ITEMS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`. As it will take too many items and requests to process at the same time, so it will take lots of memory and slow down the pc/laptop and consequently, data scraping process will slow to finish.So You can decrease these values to lower numbers (e.g. 10 and 5 or 20 to 10) to reduce the load on the system and fast scraping. You also set the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` : 0 to make it faster if you aren't getting block, if so, then you can set delay to a small value (e.g. 0.5) to slow down the requests. You also can use `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` : True, then scrapy will automatically adjust the delay between requests based on the response time of the website.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd
import scrapy_xlsx

class PlateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape_plate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {'xlsx': 'scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter'},
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'xlsx',
        'FEED_URI': 'output_r00.xlsx',
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0,
        'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 10,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 5,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': False
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        column_a_values = df['PLATE']

        for plate_num in column_a_values:
            base_url = f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            yield scrapy.Request(base_url, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={'plate_num': plate_num})

    def parse(self, response, plate_num):
        plate = response.xpath('//div[@class="resultsstrip"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//div[@class="resultsstrip"]/p/text()').extract_first()

        try:
            if plate_num == plate.replace(" ", "").strip():
                item = {"plate": plate_num, "price": price.strip()}
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate_num, "price": "-"}
        except:
            item = {"plate": plate_num, "price": "-"}

        self.logger.info(item)
        yield item

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(PlateScraper)
    process.start()
```

Comment: In this question reported that application continously reduce scraping speed during runtime. On posted log stats, that I've additionally requested I don't see usual signs that this scraping application was blocked as we see from `downloader/response_status_count/200` - all requests returned 200 response, produced ~1 item from each visited url just as defined in code and total `elapsed_time_secondsis` around 40 minutes - usually normal scraping speed from single IP.

Comment: It is strange that it starts with high speed then lowers down...it is same with given code. But I did not change Autothrottle: True I used the code as above in your code

Comment: @xlmaster, website's server may be able to handle a large number of requests at the beginning, but then slowing down or the website's server may have a built-in mechanism to detect and block scrapers, which would slow down the scraping process.

Comment: But just a week ago, it was at speed 400 items/min. Now starts with 200 then decreases gradually

Comment: This is website's updated reason, for instance, I gave an answer but after a few days, when run the same code then getting blocked

Comment: Then maybe `'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1` would bypass website blocking?

Comment: @xlmaster, Not sure. You may apply  DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1 or .50 but if you persist to test to use proxy(I'm not saying to do that as it's just slow down to scrape) , then it will take about a minute to scrape your mentioned data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251465/discussion-between-xlmaster-and-md-fazlul-hoque).

Comment: .. and this is how you get a bounty :). Clear and correct explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Those performance-related issues are sometimes really hard to crack just from the code. The problem just could be in too many places. I'd suggest you run a Profiler, two times. 1) run it while the pace is quick. 2) run it for an extended period of time for the pace to slow down. The slower pace gets, the better.

Then, compare both results. There will probably be a percentage increase in some operations. Maybe you'll see an increase in the `.xlsx` compression time as suggested before, maybe there will be a long operation searching through the cache, or maybe something completely different. This increase will point you to the right place to look for a bug.

Measuring your code could look something like that (But be sure to refer to a [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)):

```py
...
import cProfile
...

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

try:
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(plateScraper)
    process.start()
    # Press CTRL+c any time you want to finish profiling.
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

pr.disable()
# Save/print profiler results here.
```

Comment: If profiler will be used. I'd add output data ordered by cumulative time - to get the most.. time consuming function/method calls first (which is as far as I know - Is not an default option)

Answer (score 0):

On a very first look code looks Ok.
Hovewer I see several points that can lead to increasing scraping speed here:

1. `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` setting - as it didn't changed it keep default vaue 8 (no more than 8 requests at the same time). Recommended to increase it up to value of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`.
2. `CONCURRENT_ITEMS` setting - we had several reports that increasing value of this setting may lead to degrated performance -[/scrapy/issues/5182](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5182). Recommended to keep it default.
3. custom scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter (assuming that https://github.com/jesuslosada/scrapy-xlsx used here) - On a first look I didn't expected issues as usually ~3000 items is not a lot data. Hovewer technically `.xlsx` file - is zipped archive with xml documents. It uses `openpyxl` that keep all file contents and it's parsed xml trees in RAM memory. Each added row increase size of xml tree of created `.xlsx` file as result of this adding each new row - can be more CPU intensive. - Recommented to compare scraping speed with usage of scrapy built-ins feed exporters (csv or json lines).

Comment: but i export it to xlsx file, how I can use csv, json?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=csv#json-lines

Comment: I mean I need to export as xlsx file format, your link is about exporting in CSV format.

Comment: I also changed settings as per ypur description 1,2 `custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORTERS' :FEED_EXPORTERS,'FEED_FORMAT': 'xlsx','FEED_URI': 'output_r00.xlsx', 'LOG_LEVEL':'INFO','DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0,'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS':30,'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN':30,'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED':False}` same result

Comment: Just check/compare performance against scrapy built-in csv, or jsonlines feed exporter usage (no third-party xlsx) - if it will work faster - then root-cause of this are inefficient third-party xlsx exporter You use - if results the same - it is something else.

Comment: Because on Your code I don't see anything else that may.. continiously reduce scraping RPM rate during runtime.

Comment: In case if with csv/jsonlines feed exporter application will work faster and You still need xlsx - I'd suggest to use csv/jsonline exporter - and separately after `process.start()` convert it to xlsx. As xlsx writing will be after - it will not delay requests during scraping.
My answer created assuming that You have **gradually** decreasing req/minute rate I mean slowly reduce for example from 300, 297, 295, .… to 50. Rpm spikes like 400 on 1st minute to 100 on 2nd to 200 on 3d - is not gradually.. it's completely different and sometimes - expected due to specifics of scrapy archintecture

Comment: Have you tested the script. It is same as you mentioned decreases from higher rate to lower per minute

Answer (score 0):

Discovering a straightforward method to address the issue of slowing scrapers over time can greatly enhance your web scraping efficiency. Using **Selenium** in combination with strategic pauses and server changes can significantly improve the robustness of your scraping operations. Let's delve into this process in detail:

**1. Pausing the Scraper When it Slows Down:**

When your scraper encounters a slowdown, you can effectively pause it using the **WebDriverWait(driver, time)** method within a try-except block. Set the "time" parameter to an appropriate value based on your specific program requirements. Here's how it works: if the program experiences a slowdown, it will fail to meet the WebDriverWait condition and trigger the except block. In this except block, you can pause the scraper by requesting user input, typically by pressing Enter, like:
input("Press enter to continue: )
Meanwhile, during this pause, you can proceed to change the server.

**2. Changing Servers:**

Before changing servers, it's important to understand why this step is crucial. When numerous requests are sent from a single connection, certain websites may either block the IP address or throttle the connection speed to prevent potential Denial-of-Service (DoS) attacks. Hence, it's advisable to switch servers and begin afresh. To achieve this, you can employ various methods. A straightforward approach is to utilize a **VPN service**. While free options like [Psiphon][1] are available, they tend to have limited longevity and may slow down quickly. As a starting point, you can experiment with these free options. If they don't resolve the issue satisfactorily, consider upgrading to paid VPN services like Nord or ExpressVPN. These paid services offer a multitude of servers to choose from, allowing you to effortlessly switch servers whenever your scraper encounters slowdowns.

**3. Resuming the Scraper:**

Once the VPN connects, you can press "Enter" as input to signal the scraper to continue from where it left off in step 1. This will again speed up your scraper speed as the request will be going through a new connection.

If it slows down again, simply repeat the steps outlined from 1 to 3.

By implementing this strategy, you can significantly enhance the resilience and efficiency of your web scraping endeavors.

Comment: Please do not use AI to answer questions.

Comment: I've not used to AI to answer the question, I've written the complete answer by myself