# Web scraper becomes slow after sometime

Tags: python, web-scraping, timeout, ip, ip-address

I've written a Python web scrapper code and I'm trying to fetch data from a dynamic website, but the problem is that the website I'm scrapping data from tracks IPs and slows the response time.
Right now I've used a condition in the code that if there is no response for 'x' seconds, it'll pause the program and ask the user to change the IP, To change the IP, I'm using a free proxy software: Psiphon (https://psiphon.ca/en/download.html?psiphonca) but that don't work for long maybe because those are free VPNs.
Maybe I can use a Paid VPN but I'm not sure.

Is there any way I can workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a paid VPN service: NordVPN, which solved the issue.
You can choose from multiple VPNs like Express or Nord or whichever you find best fit.

You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77028694/10495410 for detailed process.